# related to php arithmetic

Tags: php

```
$y = 013;
echo $y + 5; //this result in 16
```

I can not figure it out how its ans is 16? Can any one help?

Comment: For some reason it is interpreting 013 as 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because 013 isn't decimal (base 10). it's octal (base 8). the value in decimal is:
(0 * 8^2) + (1 * 8^1) + (3 * 8^0) = 0 + 8 + 3 = 11

which gives the correct (though unexpected, at least by you) result of 16 when added to 5.

**moral of the story:** don't prepend a number literal with 0 unless you know what it means

Comment: "moral of the story: don't prepend a number literal with 0 unless you know what it means" 
I dont agree with this, since its not so clear that 013 is octal...since in algebra 013=13. but in PHP I agree with the moral of story :P

Comment: It's part of PHP syntax, not algebra. Literal integers with a leading 0 are always octal in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

number with leading zero is octal number

[like](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

```
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal
```

> Integers can be specified in decimal
>   (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), or
>   octal (base 8) notation, optionally
>   preceded by a sign (- or +).
>
> To use octal notation, precede the
>   number with a 0 (zero). To use
>   hexadecimal notation precede the
>   number with 0x.

Answer (score 0):

$y = 013;
echo $y + 5;

013 is octal number  all php integer numbers are octal .

show this link. first.

http://www.ascii.cl/conversion.htm